# How to merge two nominal attributes into one?

Tags: r

```
a=c("A","B","C")
b=c("a","b","c")
df=(a,b)
```

What I want is a data.frame with only one attribute and values `"A a", "B b", "C c"`. It's merging two columns and adding space in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = paste(a,b))
```

`x` is just the name you want for that one column.

Comment: Thank you, if anyone needs this in the future, I figured out:

df <- data.frame(x = paste(a,b, sep=" "))

adds the space.

Comment: @Palcente `sep` is already `" "` by default, you don't need to indicate it.